# Как кастомизировать компоненты React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Создатели `React` перенесли `Bootstrap` под свою гребенку. При работе с данной библиотекой [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html), возник вопрос, как кастомизировать стили компонентов? Как к прмиеру в сложные компоненты добавить свои классы?Получается, что бутстрап классы инкапсулированы в компоненты реакта. В документации предлагается использовать `bsStyle`,и задать инлайн-стили, но как быть,если я к примеру в компонент хочу добавить свой класс?Или не хочу использовать инлайн стили?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3hg89yt/2/

Comment: спасибо за ответ. вы не могли бы перенести это дело в ответ,чтобы я его выбрал и закрыл вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У компонентов **React-Bootstrap** есть `props` c названием `bsClass` - по умолчанию там стоит Bootstrap-овский класс.
При установке `bsClass="qwerty"` у этого компонента будет `class="qwerty"`

jsfiddle.net/m3hg89yt/2

Comment: Добавьте код в ответ, а то внешний ресурс может заэкспайриться и код потеряется.